# Need help solving Flutter pixels assetion error

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I keep getting this assertion error pixel!=null from a stream builder if statement, it wont return anyting from the if, only from the else. thank you. very confused

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("ffff23223r");
    return new StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().asStream(),
        builder: (context, theuser) {
                   {
            if(theuser.hasData && theuser.data.isEmailVerified){
            return  Container(color:Colors.red
            );//always gives me error
          }
          else{return intro(theuser);//works fine no matter whats here  }
          }
        });  
  }
```

the error:

> Exception has occurred.
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart': Failed assertion:
>   line 661 pos 12: 'pixels != null': is not true.
>
> static _doThrowNew(int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object
>   message) native "AssertionError_throwNew";

Comment: You need to give your Container a height

Comment: Just tried that and adding a width, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I found that it was needed to be put in a tabbar view:

```
 return new StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().asStream(),
    builder: (context, theuser) {
      {
        return Scaffold(
          body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
            theuser.hasData && theuser.data.isEmailVerified
                ? main2MapPage(theuser)
                : new intro(theuser),
          ]),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        );
      }
    });
```